# Error to parse a JSON file in Swift 3

Tags: json, swift

I´m newbie in Swift and I have some problems with parsing JSON using Swift 3 code.

This is my JSON (extract):

```
[  
   {  
      "COD_USUARIO":"4",
      "0":"4",
      "USUARIO":"PIEDAD",
      "1":"PIEDAD",
      "CLAVE":"MU\u00d1OZ",
      "2":"MU\u00d1OZ",
      "ACTIVO":"1",
      "3":"1",
      "FECHA_ALTA":"2010-12-07 00:00:00",
      "4":"2010-12-07 00:00:00",
      "FECHA_BAJA":null,
      "5":null,
      "CIF":null,
      "6":null,
      "TELEFONO_CASA":"",
      "7":"",
      "TELEFONO_MOVIL":"",
      "8":"",
      "EMAIL_TRABAJO":"",
      "9":"",
      "EMAIL_PARTICULAR":"",
      "10":"",
      "COLOR":"16777215",
      "11":"16777215",
      "ADMINISTRADOR":"0",
      "12":"0",
      "COD_PERSONA":"9",
      "13":"9",
      "IMPRESORA_ETIQUETAS":"",
      "14":"",
      "IMP_JUSTIFICANTES":"",
      "15":"",
      "VER_SESIONES":"0",
      "16":"0",
      "COD_EMPRESA":"0",
      "17":"0",
      "FECHA_TRABAJO":null,
      "18":null,
      "MEMORIZAR_FECHA":"0",
      "19":"0",
      "AVISOS_PAGOS":"0",
      "20":"0",
      "AVISOS_COBROS":"0",
      "21":"0",
      "AVISOS_DIAS":"0",
      "22":"0",
      "AVISOS_CONTRATOSC":"0",
      "23":"0",
      "24":"0"
   }
]
```

And this is my code (extract):

```
let url = URL(string : "http://192.168.0.252:6996/datos/policlinica/webservices/valida.php")
let session = URLSession.shared

let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url!)
request.httpMethod = "POST"

let paramToSend = "usu=" + user + "&pass=" + pwd

request.httpBody = paramToSend.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
    guard let _:Data = data else{
        return
    }

    do {
        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])
        print (json) //I can see my json in console

        let cod_persona = json["COD_USUARIO"]
        print (cod_persona)
        //error: Type 'Any' has no subscript members
    } catch {
        print ("error")
        return
    }
})
task.resume()
```

I have tried many examples of the internet, but I can not read a specific JSON data. For example, I would like to read the "COD_USUARIO" field and save the data in a variable, but I can not get it to work well for me.

Any advice on this theme or what am I doing wrong (sure many things)

Comment: First of all, your JSON is an Array at top level, not a Dictionary. So `json["COD_USUARIO"]` wouldn't work. This causes an error because when you do `["COD_USUARIO"]` you are using subscript. You acts like it was a Dictionary, but you didn't tell the compiler to think so. You need to use a "as Dictionary" (at least). Well, now that I said it, it's not a Dictionary, but an Array, so "json as Array", then "json.first as Dictionary", etc.

Comment: Please [search on the error](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+Type+%27Any%27+has+no+subscript+members) before posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that your json contains array objects, so I would call it like:

```
json[0]["COD_USUARIO"]
```

Because `COD_USUARIO` is in the first array of the json.

Comment: Great, that was exactly the mistake and it solved the problem! Thanks you Tamas, you are greater!! :D